# How can I tell if a method is a result of a get or a post from inside my MVC action filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have methods like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(BaseViewModel vm) {

    public ActionResult Delete(string ac) {
        try {
```

From within my action filter is there a way that I can check if the method is a post or get ?

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
```

??

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The [`ActionExecutingContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext.aspx) has a [`HttpContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.httpcontext.aspx) property. From there, you can obtain the [`Request`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.request.aspx) property, which has a [`HttpMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.httpmethod.aspx) property, which tells you which method was used in this request.

Comment: FYI; public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext){ var isPostBack = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == "POST" }

Comment: or `context.HttpContext.Request.Method`

Comment: `HttpMethod` property name is changed to `Method` in .net core.