# MVC Model Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

My ultimate question is this - should a model binder populate **all** of the model, or only the bits that are being posted, leaving the controller to populate the rest?

For example, I am adding a product in my system and on the form i want the user to select which sites the new product will appear on. Therefore, in my model I want to populate a collection called "AllAvailableSites" to render the checkboxes for the user to choose from. I also need to populate the model with any chosen sites on a post in case the form does not validate, and I need to represent the form showing the initial selections. It would seem that I should let the model binder set the chosen sites on the model, and (once in the controller method) I set the "AllAvailableSites" on the model. Does that sound right? It seems more efficient to set everything in the model binder but someone is suggesting it is not quite right.

I am grateful for any advice; I have to say that all the MVC model binding help online seems to cite really simple examples, nothing complicated.

Also, do I really need a GET and a POST version of a method? Can't they just take the same view model? Then I check in my model binder if it is a GET/POST, and populate all the model accordingly.

Comment: Can you actually tell if something has been GET'd or POST'd? Edit: yes you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629624/how-can-i-tell-if-a-method-is-a-result-of-a-get-or-a-post-from-inside-my-mvc-act Still a horrible idea imo

Comment: Can you post your GET and POST methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial conclusion is sound. A model binder should only worry about creating an instance of a model and populating its properties with the values it has available to it from the action context (for example, post values), and then performing validation. Your controller is then responsible for populating any additional values required for the view, such as your list of available sites.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean about needing separate GET/POST methods. If you are saving or creating an instance of a model, you should be posting, so it would seem the GET part is irrelevant. Unless you mean something like:

```
[HttpGet, ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult Edit(MyModel model)
{
   return View(model);
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult SaveEdit(MyModel model)
{
   // validate and save, then
   return View(model);
}
```

Perhaps you are wondering if you can just combine them into one action and just figure out if they are viewing the edit form or posting the results of the edit form within the action. I would strongly encourage you not to do this. There is a variety of reasons, but let's just  keep it at that; don't do it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just to clarify, by separate GET/POST methods i meant what you have done by having a separate controller method for Edit when GET or POST. I'm wondering about your GET version of the edit method, because it takes a model instance it will have run through my model binder class even though it is a GET but nothing will have been populated - can i check if its a GET/POST in my model binder and save it the trouble of checking for things that are not there? Im guessing the controller then loads the entity from the DB and not the model binder?

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't have to. It should skip over the properties that it has no values for. Binders normally use a ValueProvider, which can parse values from a form post, JSON post, query string arguments, etc. The binder should go through each eligible property on the model and try to get a value from the ValueProvider. If there isn't one, it should skip over it.

Comment: Hmm and there was me just checking Request.Form in my model binder. Im reticent to use default binding because my form is quite complicated and most of the controls on it will be duplicated (ie if my product is going to show on 3 sites then the description can vary for each and so i have 3 controls on my form called Description_Site1, Description_Site2 etc). The num of sites can vary so model cant have a simple property for each, would need a list. Also have a grid that appears later on page which can have additional rows added on the fly -i just dont trust the defaultmodelbinder....should i ?

Comment: Sorry dude, im sure this is all basic stuff to you, i think i need to go on a course! (certainly not much good literature on the web for mvc). Thanks for your help, i appreciate it.

Comment: It's not a problem. It's easy to get turned around in how model binding, validation, and value providers work, and to just say "screw this thing, i'll just override it with my own". Most of the time, however, you can get it to do most of the work for you with a little knowledge and some refactoring. Even if you really need to use your own binder, you'll probably want to have it derive from DefaultModelBinder so you can use some of the built-in logic for getting values, validating, etc. If you post your model and point out the problems you're having, I'm sure we can figure it out.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is really kind of you. I am in the middle of moving my code around based on the discussions we have had so far, and im about to run off to a meeting unfortunately. I will post something later this afternoon. Although i would be hugely grateful for any advice i really dont expect any so please only answer at your leisure (feeling a bit bad now!)